# No filename when uploading a file

Tags: php

I found a code online for uploading a file(a picture) from a form. It works great, but I want it to write the file name into a table, like the rest of the data from the form. I'm using this code

```
           ?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file1"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file1"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file1"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      copy($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; 
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: so...you copy paste from the internet (i think this is taken from w3schools)without knowing how the code works and now you ask others to do your job....dude...put some effort in it...

Comment: @SpiderLinked actually I've put a lot of work into understanding the code after I copied, I've also changed it to suit my needs,and it's only a small part of the webpage, but the detail I'm asking you people for help, eludes my current knowladge of php. If i get an aswer that works, I'll put an effort into finding out why it works, not just paste it in

Comment: fixed it i had 
$db_file=strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["file1"]));
 and I corrected it to
 $db_file=strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_FILES["file1"]["name"]));